# iOS firmware incompatible with my iPad 2 GSM

Tags: ios8

I have an iPad 2 GSM (know that cus it has a sim) and I am a Apple Developer. I've created an app in Swift and I need to test it. I downloaded the file called 'iPad3,1_8.0_12A4297e_Restore.ipsw' and I alt/option clicked the restore button and selected the ipsw. Then it displayed 'The ipad is not compatible with this firmware file' any fixes? I'm trying to redownload.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iPad2, then it will not be compatible with the iPad3 restore file.  If you do not see an iPad2 restore file, then the iPad2 will probably not be upgradable to iOS8.

Edit: I do see a restore file for the iPad2, make sure you are downloading the right file by checking the number on the back of your iPad and making sure it matches the download file number.

Comment: Indeed, [`iPad3,1`](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iPad3,1) is the model ID for the 3rd-gen, non-GSM model.

Answer (score 0):

Download the link highlighted in red. I have same device and updated.
Reminder: You may want to backup SHSH before update or you can't downgrade to iOS 7

[image]